# GaN @ low voltage

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, efficiency, gan

Is it possible to achieve a better efficiency with GaN rather than Si at low voltage (<~ 20V)

I mean GaN is known for having low parasitic capacitors and so it allows to have low switching losses. But at low voltage, the switching losses are not so important compared to higher voltage (> 100V). The Rds(on) of GaN is better than Si but not so much and so the conduction losses are almost the same. So is it really relevant to use GaN at low voltage?

I added one Si [MOSFET](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-BSZ034N04LS-DataSheet-v02_03-EN.pdf?fileId=db3a304342371bb001424c3fe5bc7083) and a GaN [HEMT](https://epc-co.com/epc/Portals/0/epc/documents/datasheets/EPC2055_datasheet.pdf) for making the comparaison easier. They seems to be comparable.

GaN is obviously better than Si but the question is how many points of efficiency you will obtain for a low voltage application.

Comment: You choose what is relevant for the target design, reliability and cost. Other than that and, in the absence of data sheet X and data sheet Y, it's a matter of opinion.

Comment: I guess a 20 V GaN HEMT would have an impractically short channel. So manufacturing boundary conditions would affect real performance and the advantage over Si could dwindle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GaN HEMT heterojunction JFETs have an attractive FOM of die size (and thus gate charge) to breakdown voltage for a given Rds(on) so they are good for high voltage at high frequency.

FETs have a *die area* that roughly scales with breakdown voltage *squared* for a given Rds(on). The wide bandgap semiconductors have a higher critical field Ec, however. So the advantage over Si MOSFETs is pronounced at high voltages, and can make up for the other disadvantages in some applications.

They are majority carrier devices so don't have reverse recovery losses, however reverse conduction voltage (and thus conduction losses in reverse) will be relatively high.

They are also expensive compared to silicon devices (generally built on a silicon substrate plus GaN/AlGaN layers).

So high voltage and high frequency at moderate power levels are their niche.

Comment: They solved the "squared" issue, actually -- that's what SuperJunction is all about. This has made ~kV parts as practical as any other device, and has nearly eliminated 300-500V parts as those with 600-700V ratings are good enough to cover for them.  SJ is difficult to employ below 200V or so, so you still get trench VDMOS down there.

Comment: The SJ structure brings with it a new mode of energy loss, though (think of it as Coss dielectric loss), so it's not perfect; this still limits high-efficiency resonant Si designs to 100s kHz. SiC and GaN do not use SJ (AFAIK), basically because a 1200V SiC transistor is comparable feature size as a 200V Si transistor, and SJ can't be fabbed effectively at that scale (yet).

Comment: @TimWilliams Interesting, thanks. It's always a problem for new technology competing against entrenched (so to speak) technology because they keep finding ways to extend the life and because cost matters. Mechanical HDDs for example.

Answer (score 1):

GaN FETs have less loss at high switching frequencies where they do well. Plus, the reverse conduction path between the source and drain doesn't suffer from recovery issues like a MOSFET's body diode, but, does have a fairly high voltage drop of close to 2 volts.